# Redirect all GET queries from one site to another

Tags: php, url, get

Suppose I want to redirect all `GET` queries from one site to another, using `PHP`.
`POST` queries do not exist in the system.

For example, when the user connects to

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?action=myAction&pageno=2
```

I want him to be redirected to:

```
www.mySecondSite.com/index.php?action=myAction&pageno=2
```

I can get write a hard-coded code for each and every possible `$_GET` variable (`myAction` and `pageno` in my example), but it does not sound like a reasonable solution. Also, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910740/redirect-all-pages-of-one-tld-to-another) solution which involves modifying the configuration of the Apache server. Suppose I **can't** change the server configuration.

For sure, there must be a way to get all of the variables and their values, and redirect it to another site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to get complete URL, for example for my local server:

```
http://localhost/server_var.php?foo=bar&second=something
```

Try printing `$_SERVER` variable with `print_r()`:

```php
print_r( $_SERVER);
```

You should get result like this:

```
Array
(
    ...
    [REQUEST_URI] => /server_var.php?foo=bar&second=something
    ...
)
```

For more info take a look at [manual page](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server.php), so now you have your URL:

```php
$url = 'http://www.mySecondSite.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

And you can use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect your request:

```php
header( 'Location: ' . $url);
```

I recommend taking look at [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), `3xx` ones, whether you want to use `302 Found` (the default) or `307 Temporary Redirect`...

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it
>   send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT
>   (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code
>   has already been set.

So you can do this:

```php
header('HTTP/1.0 307 Temporary Redirect');
header( 'Location: ' . $url);
```

Comment: @yes123 I've provided my source in answer... It's "w3c on HTTP codes" they claim that `307 Temporary Redirect`, `302 Found`... (click on link for HTTP status codes please) and I personally find w3.org more reliable than wiki.

Comment: the difference between the 2 is pretty subtile.. i would stick with 302 personally for a temp redirect

Comment: @yes123 I don't change it neither, but it was meant as "If you are interested you can get more info here", for case he will need it in future. + for permanent redirects (301) it's worth knowing that there are more statuses than just 302. Again. Was meant as study material :)

Comment: @Andrey I recommend studying all `$_SERVER` subvariables (and keys), for case you won't need whole `REQUEST_URI` or so :)

Answer (score 4):

Write this php code at the top of the index.php page before your html tag.

```
<?
$newUrl = "www.mySecondSite.com/index.php";
if (!empty($_GET)){
$parameter = $_GET;
$firstTime = true;
foreach($parameter as $param => $value){
    if ($firstTime) {
        $newUrl .= "?" . $param . "=" . $value;
        $firstTime = false;
    } else {
        $newUrl .= "&" . $param . "=" . $value;
    }
}
}
header("Location: ".$newUrl);
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you're not using `http_build_query($_GET)` instead of your loop?

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting in .htaccess would be the way to go, but if you say you can't change that you can insert a conditional header with a 301 code in your index.php file:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

You have the contents of the query string available in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`