# Redirect all pages of one TLD + a single directory to the root of another TLD

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

In [Redirect all pages of one TLD to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910740/redirect-all-pages-of-one-tld-to-another) there's a clear example of how to Redirect from the root of one TLD to the root of another TLD. But I want add a Rewrite Condition & Rule to my .htaccess file that will do the following redirects...

```
www.example.com/one  -->  www.example.co.uk
www.example.com/one/two  -->  www.example.co.uk/two
www.example.com/one/two/three  -->  www.example.co.uk/two/three
```

So basically it will redirect the URL to one where the TLD is changed and the first directory in the path (/one) is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this should be in your vhost for `www.example.com`

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/one(.*) www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`R=301` causes the browser to cache the answer and send the next request to that target directly to the according URL. So clear your cache while testing ;)

Or, if you don't want to see the requestor that he is being redirected:

```
 RewriteRule ^/one(.*) www.example.net/$1 [P,L]
```

Which requires the `mod_proxy` module to be activated.

---

One a sidenote: plz use `example.com` in examples, because `domain` can't be used ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer & sidenote. domain.com updated to example.com in my answer.
Would this be syntactically the same if I was putting the redirect in my .htaccess file rather than my vhost.conf?

Comment: should be the same :)